# SBT file for Spark Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to SBT. I am trying to create a project with a simple producer and consumer using spark and scala. Do I need to add anything else in this SBT file? Using IDEA Intellij. Spark 2.2, CDH 5.10, Kafka 0.10

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

name := "consumer"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0.cloudera1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0.cloudera1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0.cloudera1"


resolvers ++= Vector(
  "Cloudera repo" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
)
```

Comment: I suggest starting building your application and on the go you will see do you need any additional dependencies. That is difficult to say on that point do you need any additional dependencies because there is no enough information.